# sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Update 1:
The other line works (Thanks for the help!). Now i tried to run the following, and this wont work either, i get an error for line 13: sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

the code is as follows:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Progress(Id INTEGER PRIMARY, Username STRING, Topic1 STRING, Topic2 STRING, Topic3 STRING, Topic4 STRING, 1Result STRING, 2Result STRING, 3Result STRING, 4Result STRING, TResut STRING, TCorrect INTEGER, TWrong INTEGER, TAttempted INTEGER)")
cur.exectue("INSERT INTO Progress VALUES(1, 'Admin', 'Algebra', 'Number', 'Shape, Space and Measures', 'Handling Data', '100%', '100%', '100%', '100%', '100%', '10', '0', '10')")
```

I have created an SQL Table as shown below and am trying to input some data into the table, but i keep getting the following error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "1": syntax error

```
con = lite.connect('Records.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Questions(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Question STRING, Answer STRING, Mark INTEGER, Topic STRING, Incorrect STRING, QType STRING)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Questions(1, 'What is 2/3 of 6?', '4', '1', 'Fractions', 'None', 'Numerical')")
```

Comment: You have a couple of correct answers below.  But also note that it's advisable to use the "full" version of this command `INSERT INTO Questions (ID, Question, Answer, Mark, Topic, Incorrect, QType) VALUES (1, 'What is 2/3 of 6?', '4', '1', 'Fractions', 'None', 'Numerical')` as it's more secure against later changes to the database structure.

Comment: Ohhhh.... i forgot VALUES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`INSERT` statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) is wrong; you need the `VALUES` keyword in there. It should be:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Questions VALUES (1, 'What is 2/3 of 6?', '4', '1', 'Fractions', 'None', 'Numerical')")
#                          --------^^^^^^
```

You were placing the column *values* where SQL would expect a (optional) list of column *names*.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for what you want to do can be found at, http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

In your example, you would enter,

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Questions(Id INTEGER, Question STRING, Answer STRING)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Questions VALUES(1, 'What is 2/3 of 6?', '4')")
```

I find it helpful to have an sqlite environment handy for testing before committing to Python code.